# rails: heroku deployment: database migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have an app that works fine locally. I have deployed it to heroku and done database migration with:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and I've got response:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3607
```

I assumed this means it should be fine and I can see the database in heroku admin dashboard, and it's 6.5MB, which means it's not empty. Static pages on the site work fine, but but when I try to open a page that uses data I get an error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

When I look at heroku logs it looks like there is an issue with data not loading. Error message is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass)
```

which is the error message I would get if I didn't have data.

When I go into heroku rails console and type:

```
Model.count
```

I get 0. Now what?